# Haskell - calculating an Int *100 : why does one way work, however, the other way provides an error?

Tags: function, haskell, casting, int

I am new to haskell and am trying to learn why certain things do not compile in haskell. For example, I get the following error:

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int -> Float’
                  with actual type ‘Float’
    • Possible cause: ‘(/)’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: (fromIntegral x :: Float) / 100.0
      In an equation for ‘percent’:
          percent x = (fromIntegral x :: Float) / 100.0
```

For this code:

```
percent :: Int -> Int -> Float
percent x =  (fromIntegral x :: Float) * 100.0
```

Or something like this:

```
    percent :: Int -> Int -> Float
    percent x =   a * 100.0
        where a = fromIntegral x :: Float
```

While, this method works, that I found on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303251/haskell-converting-int-to-float),  that is slightly more complex as it divides two ints before it multiplies the 100? It follows a similar methodology as the ones I coded as well that involve only one int multiplied by 100. The second one I coded, I modeled after the code seen below. I'm not confused as to why the above do not work, however, the one below that is doing a similar thing works.

```
percent :: Int -> Int -> Float
percent x y =   100 * ( a / b )
  where a = fromIntegral x :: Float
        b = fromIntegral y :: Float
```

I would appreciate the assistance as I am new to Haskell and still trying to learn how it operates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your type says the function takes two `Int` arguments:

```
percent :: Int -> Int -> Float
```

But your implementation takes only one:

```
percent x = {- ... -}
```

Change one or the other of these.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I am still trying to grasp how to define the types. Your description was very clear.